useFormContext and saving outside form
I'm trying to create a UI in which click a button opens a pop-up and in there i'm having a form, there's a save button to save the form too. I'm using shadcn components. Inside the pop-up i have my custom component in which i'm having my form.
In parent component openModal function is called when a button is clicked
const methods = useForm<ProductType>({
    defaultValues: {
      productTitle: '', 
    }
    mode:'all'
  });


const openModal = (props? :CellContext<ProductType, unknown>) => {
    return(
      <Dialog>
        <DialogTrigger asChild>
          {
            props? 
            <div>
              {props?.getValue() as string}
            </div> :
            <Button variant="outline" className='mr-4' >
              <PlusIcon/>
            </Button>
          }
        </DialogTrigger>
        <DialogContent className='w-[600px] max-w-[700px]'>
          <DialogHeader>
            <DialogTitle>Edit ERG</DialogTitle>
          </DialogHeader>
          <div>
            <FormProvider {...methods}>
              <ProductSurveyForm />
            </FormProvider>
          </div>
          <DialogFooter>
            <DialogClose asChild>
              <Button type="button" variant="secondary">
                Close
              </Button>
            </DialogClose>
            <Button form='product-form' type="submit" onClick={methods.handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>Save changes</Button>
          </DialogFooter>
        </DialogContent>
      </Dialog>
    )
  }

and in the child component i have
const { register, handleSubmit, watch, control, setValue, formState: { errors } } = useFormContext()

<form id='product-form' onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} noValidate className=''>
<Input id='productTitle' placeholder='Product Title' {...register("productTitle", {
    validate: {
    customRequired : (val: string) => {
       eturn val.trim().length === 0 && "title is required"
     }
     },
     maxLength: { value: 12, message: 'Title cannot exceed 12 letters'}
})}/>
{
   errors.productTitle && 
   <span className='text-red-500 place-self-start pt-1 pl-1'>{errors.productTitle?.message}</span>
}

I want to trigger my save function(onSubmit) somehow in the parent component.
but this code isnt triggering in that function. what am i doing wrong here.
PS: i have tried placing the save button inside the formProviver. also in another attempt i have tried shifting the whole form to the parent keeping the rest of the child component same. still no change in output

There's multiple ways you could approach this.
Personally, I'd say the best bet would be to have the parent be the one creating the form and passing it to the child (the form) by props. That way the handleSubmit(onSubmit) should technically be available at the parent level.

Another choice, if you really need to "share" the client's function to the parent, you can use something like useImperativeHandle. This hook allows you to assign properties from within a component through a ref. This way you can use variables/functions created in your child component from its parent.
If you want an example on how useImperativeHandle works like, you can check out this CodeSandbox:


Something like this should work?
Parent:
import { useRef } from 'react';

const openModal = (props? :CellContext<ProductType, unknown>) => {
  const formRef = useRef(null);

  // formRef.current?.submit is now the handleSubmit(onSubmit) function from the form.

  return (
    ...
    <ProductSurveyForm ref={formRef} />
    ...
  );
};

Form:
import { useImperativeHandle, forwardRef } from 'react';

export const ProductSurveyForm = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  const { register, handleSubmit, watch, control, setValue, formState: { errors } } = useFormContext();

  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => {
    return {
      submit: handleSubmit(onSubmit)
    }
  });

  return (
    <form id='product-form' onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} noValidate className=''>
    <Input id='productTitle' placeholder='Product Title' {...register("productTitle", {
    validate: {
    customRequired : (val: string) => {
       eturn val.trim().length === 0 && "title is required"
     }
     },
     maxLength: { value: 12, message: 'Title cannot exceed 12 letters'}
})}/>
    {
     errors.productTitle && 
     <span className='text-red-500 place-self-start pt-1 pl-1'> 
       {errors.productTitle?.message}
     </span>
   }
}
});


I don't think the codesandbox demo is working as expected. call from parent isn't causing any change in UI.

My bad, just fixed it. The problem was that the Parent was receiving an old reference to the sharedFunc function. It's working now, thanks.
